How can I know whether my RL stock trading model is over-performing because it is that good or because there's a glitch in the code?
I'm trying to make a reinforcement learning stock trading algorithm. It's relatively simple with only options of buy,sell,hold in a custom environment. I've made two versions of it, both using the same custom environment with a little difference. One performs its actions by training on RL algorithms from stable-baselines3. The other has predict_trend method within the environment which uses previous data and financial indicators to judge what action it should take next. I've set a reward fucntion such that both the algorithms give +1,0,-1 at the end of the episode.It gives +1 if the algorithm has produced a profit by at least x percent.It gives 0 if the profit is less than x percent or equal to initial investment and -1 if it is a loss. Here's the code for bith and an image of their outputs:-
Version 1 (which uses stable-baselines3)
import gym
from gym import spaces
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from stable_baselines3 import PPO, DQN, A2C
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv

# Custom Stock Trading Environment
#This algorithm utilizes the stable-baselines3 rl algorithms
#to train the environment as to what action should be taken



class StockTradingEnv(gym.Env):
    def __init__(self, data, initial_cash=1000):
        super(StockTradingEnv, self).__init__()
        self.data = data
        self.initial_cash = initial_cash
        self.final_investment = initial_cash
        self.current_idx = 5  # Start after the first 5 days
        self.shares = 0
        self.trades = []
        self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(3)  # Hold, Buy, Sell
        self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low=-np.inf, high=np.inf, shape=(5,), dtype=np.float32)

    def reset(self):
        self.current_idx = 5
        self.final_investment = self.initial_cash
        self.shares = 0
        self.trades = []
        return self._get_state()

    def step(self, action):
        if self.current_idx >= len(self.data) - 5:
            return self._get_state(), 0, True, {}

        state = self._get_state()

        self._update_investment(action)
        self.trades.append((self.current_idx, action))
        self.current_idx += 1
        done = self.current_idx >= len(self.data) - 5
        next_state = self._get_state()

        reward = 0  # Intermediate reward is 0, final reward will be given at the end of the episode

        return next_state, reward, done, {}

    def _get_state(self):
        window_size = 5
        state = self.data['Close'].iloc[self.current_idx - window_size:self.current_idx].values
        state = (state - np.mean(state))  # Normalizing the state
        return state

    def _update_investment(self, action):
        current_price = self.data['Close'].iloc[self.current_idx]
        if action == 1:  # Buy
            self.shares += self.final_investment / current_price
            self.final_investment = 0
        elif action == 2:  # Sell
            self.final_investment += self.shares * current_price
            self.shares = 0
        self.final_investment = self.final_investment + self.shares * current_price

    def _get_final_reward(self):
        roi = (self.final_investment - self.initial_cash) / self.initial_cash
        if roi > 0.50:
            return 1
        elif roi < 0:
            return -1
        else:
            return 0

    def render(self, mode="human", close=False, episode_num=None):
        roi = (self.final_investment - self.initial_cash) / self.initial_cash
        reward = self._get_final_reward()
        print(f'Episode: {episode_num}, Initial Investment: {self.initial_cash}, '
              f'Final Investment: {self.final_investment}, ROI: {roi:.3%}, Reward: {reward}')

# Train and Test with RL Model
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Load the training dataset
    train_df = pd.read_csv('MSFT.csv')
    start_date = '2023-01-03'
    end_date = '2023-12-29'

    train_data = train_df[(train_df['Date'] >= start_date) & (train_df['Date'] <= end_date)]
    train_data = train_data.set_index('Date')

    # Create and train the RL model
    env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: StockTradingEnv(train_data)])
    model = PPO("MlpPolicy", env, verbose=1)
    model.learn(total_timesteps=10000)

    # Test the model on a different dataset
    test_df = pd.read_csv('AAPL.csv')
    start_date = '2023-01-03'
    end_date = '2023-12-29'

    test_data = test_df[(test_df['Date'] >= start_date) & (test_df['Date'] <= end_date)]
    test_data = test_data.set_index('Date')

    env = StockTradingEnv(test_data, initial_cash=100)

    num_test_episodes = 10  # Define the number of test episodes
    cumulative_reward = 0

    for episode in range(num_test_episodes):
        state = env.reset()
        done = False

        while not done:
            state = state.reshape(1, -1)
            action, _states = model.predict(state)  # Use the trained model to predict actions
            next_state, _, done, _ = env.step(action)
            state = next_state
        
        reward = env._get_final_reward()
        cumulative_reward += reward
        env.render(episode_num=episode + 1)

    print(f'Cumulative Reward after {num_test_episodes} episodes: {cumulative_reward}')


enter image description here
Version 2 (using _predict_trend within the environment)
import gym
from gym import spaces
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Custom Stock Trading Environment
#This version utilizes the _predict_trend method
#within the environment to decide what action
#should be taken


class StockTradingEnv(gym.Env):
    def __init__(self, data, initial_cash=1000):
        super(StockTradingEnv, self).__init__()
        self.data = data
        self.initial_cash = initial_cash
        self.final_investment = initial_cash
        self.current_idx = 5  # Start after the first 5 days
        self.shares = 0
        self.trades = []
        self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(3)  # Hold, Buy, Sell
        self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low=-np.inf, high=np.inf, shape=(5,), dtype=np.float32)

    def reset(self):
        self.current_idx = 5
        self.final_investment = self.initial_cash
        self.shares = 0
        self.trades = []
        return self._get_state()

    def step(self, action=None):
        if self.current_idx >= len(self.data) - 5:
            return self._get_state(), 0, True, {}

        state = self._get_state()

        if action is None:
            trend = self._predict_trend()
            action = self._take_action_based_on_trend(trend)

        self._update_investment(action)
        self.trades.append((self.current_idx, action))
        self.current_idx += 1
        done = self.current_idx >= len(self.data) - 5
        next_state = self._get_state()

        reward = 0  # Intermediate reward is 0, final reward will be given at the end of the episode

        return next_state, reward, done, {}

    def _get_state(self):
        window_size = 5
        state = self.data['Close'].iloc[self.current_idx - window_size:self.current_idx].values
        state = (state - np.mean(state))  # Normalizing the state
        return state

    def _update_investment(self, action):
        current_price = self.data['Close'].iloc[self.current_idx]
        if action == 1:  # Buy
            self.shares += self.final_investment / current_price
            self.final_investment = 0
        elif action == 2:  # Sell
            self.final_investment += self.shares * current_price
            self.shares = 0
        self.final_investment = self.final_investment + self.shares * current_price

    def _get_final_reward(self):
        roi = (self.final_investment - self.initial_cash) / self.initial_cash
        if roi > 0.50:
            return 1
        elif roi < 0:
            return -1
        else:
            return 0

    def _predict_trend(self, window_size=5, ema_alpha=0.3):
        if self.current_idx < window_size:
            return "neutral"  # Default to neutral if not enough data to calculate EMA
        
        recent_prices = self.data['Close'].iloc[self.current_idx - window_size:self.current_idx].values
        ema = recent_prices[0]
        
        for price in recent_prices[1:]:
            ema = ema_alpha * price + (1 - ema_alpha) * ema  # Update EMA
        
        current_price = self.data['Close'].iloc[self.current_idx]
        if current_price > ema:
            return "up"
        elif current_price < ema:
            return "down"
        else:
            return "neutral"

    def _take_action_based_on_trend(self, trend):
        if trend == "up":
            return 1  # Buy
        elif trend == "down":
            return 2  # Sell
        else:
            return 0  # Hold

    def render(self, mode="human", close=False, episode_num=None):
        roi = (self.final_investment - self.initial_cash) / self.initial_cash
        reward = self._get_final_reward()
        print(f'Episode: {episode_num}, Initial Investment: {self.initial_cash}, '
              f'Final Investment: {self.final_investment}, ROI: {roi:.3%}, Reward: {reward}')

# Test the Environment
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Load the test dataset
    test_df = pd.read_csv('AAPL.csv')
    start_date = '2023-01-03'
    end_date = '2023-12-29'

    test_data = test_df[(test_df['Date'] >= start_date) & (test_df['Date'] <= end_date)]
    test_data = test_data.set_index('Date')

    initial_cash = 100
    env = StockTradingEnv(test_data, initial_cash=initial_cash)

    num_test_episodes = 10  # Define the number of test episodes
    cumulative_reward = 0

    for episode in range(num_test_episodes):
        state = env.reset()
        done = False

        while not done:
            state = state.reshape(1, -1)
            trend = env._predict_trend()
            action = env._take_action_based_on_trend(trend)
            next_state, _, done, _ = env.step(action)
            state = next_state
        
        reward = env._get_final_reward()
        cumulative_reward += reward
        env.render(episode_num=episode + 1)

    print(f'Cumulative Reward after {num_test_episodes} episodes: {cumulative_reward}')

enter image description here
I've used the values 0.10,0.20,0.25 and 0.30 for the x. Up til 0.3 both algorithms don't train at all in that they give 1 in all episodes. I mean their progress should be gradual,right? -1,0,0,-1, then maybe a few 1s. That doesn't happen in either.  I've tried increasing/decreasing both the initial investment (100,1000,2000,10000) and the number of episodes (10,100,200) but the result doesn't change. They perform 100% until 0.25.At 0.3 they give 0 in all episodes. Even so, it should display some sort of training. It's not happening. I want to know whether my algorithms really are that good or have a made an error in the code somewhere. And if they really are that good--which I have some doubts about--can you give me some ideas about how I can increase their performance after 0.25?
